# CCK checkboxes with no labels

Tags: entities

I'm currently creating a form where the user is supposed to check a (sometimes large) number of checkboxes. The problem is that I only want the checkboxes visible, not their label (or key) while the user is filling out the form. Is this possible?

Currently it looks like this:

[ ] label
[ ] label
[ ] label
etc.

I'm aiming for:

[ ] [ ] [ ] ... [ ]

I'm using Drupal 6.22 with CCK 6.x-2.9. Other related modules in my form that will interact with the checkboxes are Conditional Fields 6.x-2.0 and Multicolumn checkboxes/radios 6.x-1.6

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use visibility:hidden; (and height and/or width 0px). I use visibility:hidden; when display:none is not useful (issues of inheritances of CSS, or maybe still you can need the values of the hidden elements).

Other suggestion. I have several forms that use lots of checkboxes, so I use Vertical Tabs http://drupal.org/project/vertical_tabs to divide the forms in several tabs, to show only one group of checkboxes per tab. So here is not necessary to remove labels of checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the wrong way to do it, but I found the labels go away if you uncheck the 
    Use field label instead of the "On value" as label
in the Content Types->Fields dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to hide the label you could probably target it with CSS and display:none;. It's probably one of these classes: .field-label .field-label-inline .field-label-inline-first. You can check out the template files in the cck themes folder if you want to modify the behavior.

Template:
[modules folder]/cck/theme/content-field.tpl.php

Another helpful resource is hook_form_alter but with CCK you will want to review the #after_build option. This page discusses how to alter cck elements. http://drupal.org/node/726282

Comment: I read http://drupal.org/node/726282. Could you please tell me how can I achieve the 3rd point that mentioned in that page.
3. If you're trying to do anything with radios, checkboxes, or similar, you'll also notice that required properties such as #options do not exist yet, in either place. Those come later.